# Help with understanding how to sketch a graph of y=1/f(x) and y = xf(x)

Tags: asymptotics, graphing-functions

I'm having problems trying to figure out how to sketch a graph for these 2 questions. Could someone provide me a step by step guide on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: For $a)$ where would the horizontal and  vertical asymptotes be?